# Javascript Countdown going in negative 1

Tags: javascript

I created a javascript countdown timer. It's 15 mins timer. But after 15 mins it goes in negative rather than starting over again. The whole code is the HTML and js i am using for the countdown.

Here is the whole code of the countdown

```
  <div class="containers-1">
    <div class="boxes-1">
      <span class="values-1" id="minutes-1">15</span>
      <div class="labeles-1">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes-1">
      <span class="values-1" id="seconds-1">00</span>
      <div class="labeles-1">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containers-1">
    <div class="boxes-1">
      <span class="values-1" id="minutes-2">15</span>
      <div class="labeles-1">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes-1">
      <span class="values-1" id="seconds-2">00</span>
      <div class="labeles-1">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function startCountdown(timerId, minutesId, secondsId) {
  var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 9000; // 15 mins in milliseconds
  
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    document.getElementById(minutesId).innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById(secondsId).innerHTML = seconds;
    
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById(timerId).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      document.getElementById(minutesId).innerHTML = "00";
      document.getElementById(secondsId).innerHTML = "00";
      setTimeout(function() {
        startCountdown(timerId, minutesId, secondsId);
      }, 999);
    }
  }, 1000);
}


startCountdown("countdown-timer1", "minutes-1", "seconds-1");
startCountdown("labels", "minutes-2", "seconds-2");
  </script>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/csfwp8m7/

Comment: Have added the html code now

Comment: Where's the `countdown-timer1` element?

Comment: 9000 is not 15 minutes but 9 seconds ...

Comment: ignore the countdown-timer1 

startCountdown("labels", "minutes-1", "seconds-1");

use this instead

Comment: Yeah i did it 9 seconds because it faster to check it in 9 seconds rather than waiting for 15 mins

Comment: Where's the `labels` element?

Comment: its the class name labeles-1 sorry my mistake i have named it as labels in the code

Comment: there are several inaccuracies in your code.. anyway the main issue was highlighted by @derpirscher. the ms offset should be `offsetMS_15min = 1000*(60*15)`

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't have the `labels` id. `document.getElementById(timerId).innerHTML` tries to find an element with `id="labels"` – if it doesn't exist, that line throws an error. The same with `labels-1`.

Comment: @DiegoD The duration of the timer is not the issue

Comment: Hey diego so if i change the offset code will it fix the issue

Comment: No it won't, obviously.

Comment: I have updated the post with the new code

Comment: You are still missing the `countdown-timer1` and `labels` elements. It won't work until you add them. See https://jsfiddle.net/csfwp8m7/1/

Comment: @GuyIncognito is right. Check your console : document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score -1):

Change *if* condition for `distance < 1000`. This is because distance is also in miliseconds, so it have to set to 00 the timer and restart when distance is lower than 1 second, that is, 1000 miliseconds.

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
      function startCountdown(timerId, minutesId, secondsId) {
      var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 9000; // 15 mins in milliseconds
      
      var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
        document.getElementById(minutesId).innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById(secondsId).innerHTML = seconds;
        console.log(distance);
        
        if (distance < 1000) {
          clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementById(timerId).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
          document.getElementById(minutesId).innerHTML = "00";
          document.getElementById(secondsId).innerHTML = "00";
          setTimeout(function() {
            startCountdown(timerId, minutesId, secondsId);
          }, 999);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="countdown-timer1">A</p>
  <p id="minutes-1">B</p>
  <p id="seconds-1">C</p>
  <button onclick="startCountdown('countdown-timer1', 'minutes-1', 'seconds-1');">Cuenta atrás</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the changes but after 0 seconds the countdown is not starting again

Comment: It works in my case. Here's the full code. I didn't change anything apart from that, so maybe the problem is related with your browser, but try it anyways.

Comment: I am facing the same issue counter is not repeating the sequence of starting over again

Comment: @JackNezie You've been told several times now what the issue is. You're missing the "timerId" elements in the HTML.